# How to query the result of a SOQL query as IN subquery in another SOQL query?

Tags: apex, trigger, after-trigger

I am trying to use the result of a query to be used as In another query but I am getting an error. How do I solve this?

```
trigger CopyChecklistIntoLegitimation on Legitimation__c(after insert){

  //Get the related account's legalstructure of the legitimation

Account queriedLegalStructure = [Select LegalStructure__c from Account Where Id in 
                                (Select Account__c from Legitimation__c Where Id in 
                                 :Trigger.New)];
List<CheckListTemplate> listTemp = [Select name from ChecklistTemplate__c Where Entity__c = 'legitimation' And LegalStructure__c IN: queriedLegalStructure.LegalStructure__c];
}
```

My error is when I am trying to save, I get IN operator must be used with an iterable expression

Comment: What is the error message? Please **[edit]** your post to include it verbatim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use the `IN` operator straight away (no added collections) if you are filtering on Id values. If you are filtering on any other field, you have to aggregate the values into a collection and filter on that.

```
Set<String> legalStructures = new Set<String>();
for (Account record : [/*first query*/])
{
    legalStructures.add(record.LegalStructure__c);
}
List<CustomObject__c> records = [
    SELECT ... FROM CustomObject__c WHERE ... AND LegalStructure__c IN :legalStructures
];
```

Comment: But any time I only get one record associated with the legalstructure on account so I assume I do not need a collection

Comment: That is a faulty assumption. Technically you can assign a query result to a single record, but it is more brittle and will lead to unnecessary errors. Unless you are dead certain the result cannot be empty or have multiple records, you simply can't write the code that way.

Comment: Thanks for enlightening me